# Find and replace duplicates in Array, but replace each nth instance with a different string

Tags: python

I have an array below which consists of repeated strings. I want to find and replace those strings, but each time a match is made I want to change the value of the replace string.

Let me demonstrate.

This Sample Array:

```
SampleArray = ['champ', 'king', 'king', 'mak', 'mak', 'mak']
```

should get changed to:

```
SampleArray = ['champ', 'king1', 'king2', 'mak1', 'mak2', 'mak3']
```

How to make this possible? I've been going at it for 3 days now with no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
My Failed Code:

import os, collections, re

SampleArray = ['champ', 'king', 'king', 'mak', 'mak', 'mak']
dupes = [x for x, y in collections.Counter(SampleArray).items() if y > 1]
length = len(dupes)
count = 0

while count < length:
    j = 0
    instances = SampleArray.count(dupes[count])
    while j < instances:
        re.sub(dupes[count],  dupes[count] + j, SampleArray, j)
        j += 1
    count += 1
print SampleArray    
print ''; os.system('pause')
```

Comment: Shouldn't `champ` be changed to `champ1` ?

Comment: nope as its not being repeated, only king and mak are being repeated

Comment: Is the order of the items of the resulting list important ?

Comment: hehe, no hw for sure, and i posted my failed code above.

Comment: yes the order is extremely important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

numbers = { 
    word: iter([""] if count == 1 else xrange(1, count + 1)) 
    for word, count in Counter(sample).items()
}

result = [
    word + str(next(numbers[word])) 
    for word in sample
]
```

This doesn't require the list to be sorted or grouped in any way.

This solution uses [iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) to generate sequential numbers:

- first, we calculate how many times each word occurs in the list (`Counter(sample)`).
- then we create a dictionary `numbers`, which, for each word, contains its "numbering" iterator `iter(...)`. If the word occurs only once `count==1`, this iterator will return ("yield") an empty string, otherwise it will yield sequential numbers in range from 1 to count `[""] if count == 1 else xrange(1, count + 1)`.
- finally, we iterate over the list once again, and, for each word, pick the next value from its own numbering iterator `next(numbers[word])`. Since our iterators return numbers, we have to convert them to strings `str(...)`.

Comment: I've chosen this answer because it does not change the list order and also add the corrected replace string in the list. Thanks thg435

Comment: Also thg435 could you explain your code a bit, it's a bit over my head

Comment: @Ahmed: I've reformatted the code and added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks thg435, the explanation is awesome. Finally understand what is happening.

Comment: +1 Great solution. `Counter` and `iter` in the right combination.

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` is a convenient way to group duplicates:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> FinalArray = []
>>> for k, g in groupby(SampleArray):
    # g is an iterator, so get a list of it for further handling
    items = list(g)
    # If only one item, add it unchanged
    if len(items) == 1:
        FinalArray.append(k)
    # Else add index at the end
    else:
        FinalArray.extend([j + str(i) for i, j in enumerate(items, 1)])


>>> FinalArray
['champ', 'king1', 'king2', 'mak1', 'mak2', 'mak3']
```

Comment: `itertools.groupby` only groups consecutive items, doesn't it ?

Comment: Good remark: this is only valid if duplicates are consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Counter and than sorting is simpler:

```
L = ['champ', 'king', 'king', 'mak', 'mak', 'mak']
counts = Counter(L)
res = []
for word in sorted(counts.keys()):
    if counts[word] == 1:
        res.append(word)
    else:
        res.extend(['{}{}'.format(word, index) for index in 
                   range(1, counts[word] + 1)])
```

So this

```
['champ', 'mak', 'king', 'king', 'mak', 'mak']
```

also gives:

```
['champ', 'king1', 'king2', 'mak1', 'mak2', 'mak3']
```

Comment: you cheat. champ is not replaced because you append it first, not because there is only one iteration of it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to convert your array into a dictionary like that:

```
SampleDict = {}
for key in SampleArray:
    if key in SampleDict:
        SampleDict[key][0] = True # means: duplicates
        SampleDict[key][1] += 1 
    else:
        SampleDict[key] = [False, 1] # means: no duplicates
```

Now you can easily convert that dict back to an array. However if the order in `SampleArray` is important, then you can do it like that:

```
for i in range(len(SampleArray)):
    key = SampleArray[i]
    counter = SampleDict[key]
    if index[0]:
        SampleArray[i] = key + str(counter[1])
    counter[1] -= 1
```

This will give you the reversed order however, i.e.

```
SampleArray = ['champ', 'king2', 'king1', 'mak3', 'mak2', 'mak1']
```

But I'm sure you'll be able to tweak it to your needs.

Comment: but why is it champ1 and not champ only?

Comment: well this is really nice, but the order matter, and it can't just be reversed, that just puts mak(s) in front and king(s) at last, so i'll wait for a better answer, if not then i'll accept urs

Comment: you can use a defaultdict to avoid the test on key in SampleDict

Comment: and a Counter is typically a dictionary for counting items.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the array sorted :

```
import collections    
counter = collections.Counter(SampleArray)
res = []
for key in sorted(counter.keys()):
    if counter[key] == 1:
        res.append(key)
    else:
        res.extend([key+str(i) for i in range(1, counter[key]+1)])

>>> res
['champ', 'king1', 'king2', 'mak1', 'mak2', 'mak3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = ['champ', 'king', 'king', 'mak', 'mak', 'mak']

fields_out = [x + str(f.count(x) - f[i + 1:].count(x)) for i, x in enumerate(f)]
print(fields_out)

>>['champ1', 'king1', 'king2', 'mak1', 'mak2', 'mak3']
```

or

```
fields_out = [(x if i == f.index(x) else x + str(f.count(x) - f[i + 1:].count(x))) for i, x in enumerate(f)]
print(fields_out)

>>['champ', 'king', 'king2', 'mak', 'mak2', 'mak3']
```