# Best Way to Distinguish Equal List items in Python

Tags: python, list, equality

For this list:

```
['a','a','a,'b','b','c']
```

I would like to have:

```
['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','c']
```

The purpose is to get a list with different items. (`len(set(my_list)) == len(my_list)`)

It is ok to assume list is sorted.

Not every item must appear more than once (like 'c' here, in this case leave it)

There are many ways to accomplish this, I didn't think of a 'pythonic' one.

Comment: Do you need to maintain the original order? Is it ok to have `['c', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2']`?

Comment: similar/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16943968/989121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` and `itertools.count`:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lis = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
>>> c = Counter(lis)
>>> dic = {k: count(1) for k in c}
>>> [x + ( str(next(dic[x])) if c[x]>1 else '') for x in lis]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'c']
```

Using `itertools.groupby` and generator function:

```
>>> def solve(lis):
        for k,g in groupby(lis):
            le = list(g)
            if len(le) > 1:
                for i, x in enumerate(le, 1):
                    yield x+str(i)
            else:        
                yield k
...             
>>> list(solve(lis))
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'c']
```

Comment: No need to use `zip` when `enumerate` will do the job (`for i, item in enumerate(le, 1):`).  Perhaps you forgot that enumerate takes an optional `start` value?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski good point, solution updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
[ e + str(i) for i, e in enumerate(lst) ]
=> ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c5']
```

The above will generate unique names for all the values, as long as you don't mind having different numbers for each string (e.g., there won't be a `b1` if the `1` was used before)

**EDIT**

Now that the question is clear, here's another possible solution, using a functional programming style:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
c = Counter(lst)
reduce(lambda a, (k, v): a + ([k + str(i) for i in xrange(1, v+1)] if v > 1 else [k]), c.items(), [])

=> ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c', 'b1', 'b2']
```

The above will change the original order found in the input list, but if that's a problem a simple `sort()` will fix it.

Comment: maybe it was not clear, but each set (a,b and c) should have a different couters: a1 a2 a3 b1 b2

Comment: @YardenST I edited my answer with another solution, this time is correct

Comment: I was going to point out that the `reduce` can be replaced with `[k + (str(i+1) if ct > 1 else "") for k, ct in c.iteritems() for i in xrange(ct)]`, but I liked my suggestion enough that I posted it as my own answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone else is putting out their own versions, here is mine using `itertools.Counter`:

```
>>> counts = Counter(original_list)
>>> [k + (str(i+1) if ct > 1 else "") for k, ct in counts.iteritems() for i in xrange(ct)]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c', 'b1', 'b2']
```

Note that the original list order is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

```
L= ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
combined = list()

for item in set(L):
    ocr = L.count(item)
    if ocr > 1: combined += map(lambda x: item + str(x), range(1,ocr))
    else: combined.append(item)

print combined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools and a few other built-in functions:

```
import itertools

data = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
data_lists = [[y + str(x) for x, y in enumerate(it, 1)] for _, it in itertools.groupby(data)]
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((item if len(item) > 1 else item[0][:-1]) for item in data_lists))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner... not efficient or recommended!

Given the input:

```
A = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
```

Compose the output:

```
result = [(x + str(A[:i].count(x)) if A.count(x) > 1 else x) for i, x in enumerate(A)]
```